# Configure Nginx reverse proxy subdomains with dynamic DNS

Tags: nginx, dns

I have a small lab at home with several virtual machines that each has a web application:

```
http://vm1:8080

http://vm2:8081

http://vm3:8082
```

I also have a free dynamic DNS service (noip.com) that I configured on my internet router.
address for example : home.ddns.net

is it possible to use Nginx as a reverse proxy to serve each web application as a subdomain to the home domain/subdomain ?

like this:

```
http://app1.home.ddns.net:8080 => http://vm1:8080

http://app2.home.ddns.net:8081 => http://vm2:8081
```

or even this: (use port 80) ?

```
http://app1.home.ddns.net => http://vm1:8080

http://app2.home.ddns.net => http://vm2:8081
```

if that is not possible, can I use it like this? :

```
http://home.ddns.net/app1 => http://vm1:8080

http://home.ddns.net/app2 => http://vm2:8081
```

my question seems simple but I was not able to find an answer online and on stackoverflow :(

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All variants are possible, but second one is best and simple.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app1.home.ddns.net;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://vm1:8080;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app2.home.ddns.net;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://vm2:8081;
    }
}
```

See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Comment: nginx won't pickup an ip change if VM1 and VM2 change ip? Also this will fail to start nginx if the hostname cannot be resolved...

Answer (score 1):

I'm managing a custom server under a NO-IP subdomain (`*.hopto.org`, instead of `*.ddns.net`, but basically is run by the same company) and this seems not be possible. While [Alexey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35379098/1913655) may be correct regarding the nginx configuration, as of today, NO-IP doesn't allow sub-subdomains.

See last part of [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/77535) for more details. But basically this would mean allowing everyone to become *re-sellers* themselves.