# Cant Use a Subdomain in NGINX Proxy Manager

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, dyndns

I'm trying to set up the NGINX Reverse Proxy Manager on my Docker.

Now I have a DynDNS address and I work with the proxy manager because I can reach the default page of nginx proxy manager over the dyndns address.

When i try to connect a port with the standard dyndns name that I have over the proxy manager it works fine, also with SSL. But when I try to use a subdomain like `subdomain1.laptopsimon.net` nothing works: I can't create an SSL certificate and I can't even connect over http to the side.

Does anybody have an idea why I can not use Subdomains?

Also, I get this Letsencrypt Error in the LOG:

> [12/25/2022] [1:50:45 PM] [SSL      ] › ℹ  info      Requesting Let'sEncrypt certificates for Cert #9: subdomain1.laptopsimon.ddns.net
> [12/25/2022] [1:50:45 PM] [SSL      ] › ℹ  info      Command: certbot certonly --config "/etc/letsencrypt.ini" --cert-name "npm-9" --agree-tos --authenticator webroot --email "simon.hauber@outlook.de" --preferred-challenges "dns,http" --domains "subdomain1.laptopsimon.ddns.net"
> [12/25/2022] [1:50:49 PM] [Nginx    ] › ℹ  info      Reloading Nginx
> [12/25/2022] [1:50:49 PM] [Express  ] › ⚠  warning   Command failed: certbot certonly --config "/etc/letsencrypt.ini" --cert-name "npm-9" --agree-tos --authenticator webroot --email "simon.hauber@outlook.de" --preferred-challenges "dns,http" --domains "subdomain1.laptopsimon.ddns.net"
> Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
> Some challenges have failed.
> Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your DDNS provider, No-IP, doesn't support "fourth-level" subdomains (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46834583)).

You could have example.ddns.net working fine and DNS A record pointing to an IP address you have chosen, but they won't resolve e.g. test.example.ddns.net.

You can verify this yourself with command *nslookup subdomain1.laptopsimon.ddns.net*.

IIRC, that was the reason why I stopped using them and continued with duckdns.org.
There, every subdomain, even test1.test2.example.duckdns.org will resolve to same IP address.

From let'sencrypt log excerpt it's not clear to me what could be the problem. You will need to check